# Complex table merge Scenario that involves 3 tables and self referencing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

```
Source Table 

TableSource

SOurceID  Name   ParentId


Target Table

TableTarget

RefId ParentRefId SourceId  Name
```

-- RefId is a Foreign key coming from TableReference

```
Table Reference 

TableReference

RefID -- Auto increment IdentityCOlumn
```

Scenario

Need to merge(Insert/Update) TableSource and TableTArget in SUch a way that

```
1. On Each insert into TableTarget, it should insert a new RefId into TableReference and then Copy that RefId into TableTarget's RefId Column. 

2.ParentRefId also needs to be populated on the basis of ParentID in TableSource I-E
```

TableSource --Suppose TableSource Has following Records in the begining

```
SOurceID  Name         ParentId
1A         Group1       NULL
2B         GROUP2       NULL
3C         Department1   1A
4D         Department2   2B
5E         Section1      3C
6F         Section2      4D


-- I want to see TableTarget as following

RefId     SourceId     Name                ParentRefId 

1         1A           Group1              NULL as Group1 doesn't has a parent
2         2B           GROUP2              NULL as Group1 doesn't has a parent
3         3C           Department1         1 -- SourceID 3C's Parent is 1A and RefID of   1A is 1
4         4D           Department2         2 -- SourceID 4D's Parent in TableSOurce is   2B so we need to find the RefId of 2B in TableTarget to insert it here. That's 2
5         5E           Section1            3 -- PArent of 5E is 3C and RefId of 3C is 3
6         6F           Section2            4 -- PArent of 6F is 4D and RefID of 4D is 4
```

Solution:

Merging of Name and SourceID is not an issue. Problem starts when we need to Insert a new RefID in TableReference for each insert into TableTarget and then Copy that and Insert it into tableTarget. Second issue is how to Populate ParentRefID. ANy input regarding this would be higly appreciated

*** What would be the best way to do this ** 
Do we need Cursors? Should we Load them first with RefID and handle ParentRefId before loading them?***

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2008 or higher you should think of possibly using the 'Merge' statement which is new in SQL 2008 and newer.  It accounts for when two sources match on target, match on source, match on both, don't match.  And it can perform updates, deletes and inserts in a single statement.  It sounds like your issue would be a good candidate for this possibly as you are doing multiple things at once.  You can also get output conditions for this statement too of what it did to what column and reference.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a two-pass solution where you leave ParentRefID null during the first pass. There's no way in a single pass to use the just-inserted data in your tableTarget table to "look up" the reference ID of the parent except via a RBAR method.

So:

Insert into reference:

```
insert into tblReference select * from tblSource /* or whatever columns you want */
```

Insert into target with new RefID, leave parentRefID null:

```
insert into tblTarget select tblReference.refID, tblSource.SourceID, tblSource.Name, NULL as parentRefID from tblSource inner join tblReference on <-- whatever columns link reference and source tables -->
```

Batch update target with parentRefIDs:

update 
    tblTarget
set
    parentRefID = target_parent.refID
from
    tblSource
    inner join tblTarget target_parent on target_parent.sourceID = tblSource.parentID
    inner join tblTarget on tblTarget.sourceid = tblSource.sourceID

And no, you cannot just use a MERGE, since you can't use newly inserted data within the MERGE batch to pass on to subsequent inserts/updates.